# How to get value from combobox in a thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, combobox

I created a tkinter gui where you can choose values from different comboboxes.
[Comboboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2DSK.jpg)

I defined the comboboxes in a class and mapped the strings, which you can choose, to values:

```
class PropTwo(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self,parent,controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    label = tk.Label(self, text="Properties", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
    ...
    ...
     #Settings Filter Frequency
    texts2y = tk.Label(self, text = 'Choose Filter Frequency [Bandwith]', font = Standard_Font)
    texts2y.pack(side = tk.TOP, padx=5, pady=5)
    global mappingFiFreq
    global cbs2y
    self.valuesS2Y = tk.StringVar()
    fifreq =['7,81Hz','15,63Hz','31,25Hz','62,5Hz','125Hz','250Hz','500Hz',
             '1000Hz']
    mappingFiFreq = {'7,81Hz':'8', '15,63Hz':'1','31,25Hz':'2','62,5Hz':'3','125Hz':'4',
                     '250Hz':'5','500Hz':'6','1000Hz':'7' }
    cbs2y = ttk.Combobox(self,textvariable = self.valuesS2Y, values=fifreq, state = 'readonly')
    cbs2y.current(7)
    cbs2y.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda: updateCombo(cbs2y,mappingFiFreq))       
    cbs2y.pack(side = tk.TOP)

... #code for the other comoboxes has the same syntax
...

def updateCombo(combobox,direc):
    curVal = direc[combobox.get()]
    return curVal
```

and I want to get the value of the combobox in a thread:

```
class Producer:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        global cbs2y
        global mappingFiFreq
        ...
    def run():
        ...
        #for control, to see the value of the mapping
        print('mapping cbs2y: ', mappingFiFreq[cbs2y.get()])
        # i want to use the integer value
        vs2y = int(mappingFiFreq[cbs2y.get()])
        ...
```

I start the thread in the main:

```
p = Producer()
pt = threading.Thread(target = p.run, args = ())
pt.start()
```

When I execute the code, sometimes it works, sometimes there is an error which says:
KeyError: 'Expected boolean but got "??"'
and my print function of the value vs2y says: 'Value of cbs2y :',mappingFi[cbs2y.get()])
So the mapping didn't work this time.

But I don't know why there is this error only sometimes and how to solve it.

I would be really greatful for any kind of help!

Comment: tkinter is not `thread-safe`, you shouldn't use widgets in thread as you see. Maybe you should use `queue` to send data from one thread to another. Or maybe in main thread you should copy value from `cbs2y.get()` to normal variable and second thread  get from this variable.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I have a question, because actually I'm using only one thread and the combobox is defined in a 'normal class'. So what do you mean by: "use queue to send data from one thread to another"

Comment: you create one thread but program starts in so called `main thread` so finally you have two threads. So you have to send data between your thread (with `p.run()`) and `main thread` (with `PropTwo` and `combobox`)

Comment: In addition to @furas last comment: you can check the number of threads with [active_count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.active_count) function. Obviously, it will return `2` in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm new to python so sorry if it's a stupid question: The thread Producer has a while loop, where the value of cb2y.get() is needed to execute other code.  When I save this value to a variable in the main thread "PropTwo", then my variable won't get updated in the while loop.. How could I solve this?